# stability of essential spectra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, perturbation-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space. $A$ and $B$ are linear closed and densely defined operators and $\lambda\in\rho(A)\cap\rho(B)$ such that $(\lambda - A)^{-1}-(\lambda - B)^{-1}$ is a Frehholm perturbation then it is well known that $\sigma_e(A) = \sigma_e(B)$ where

$\sigma_{e}(A): = \{\lambda \in\mathbb{C}\,\,\hbox{such that} \ \lambda-A  \,\,\hbox{isn't a Fredholm operator on}\, X \}$.

In the proof of this result, the authors suppose $\lambda = 0$? why?(see page 288) [paper](http://www.google.tn/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X01975018&ei=xPZXU-O4B5GT0QXq04CYAQ&usg=AFQjCNGY6REa78QMKVflkmuzEWLILIIC3w&bvm=bv.65177938,d.Yms&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

That is simply the fact that you can replace $A$ and $B$ with $\lambda-A$ and $\lambda-B$ respectively.

This works because $\sigma(A+\lambda)=\sigma(A)+\lambda$. Indeed, $(A+\lambda)-\gamma$ is invertible if and only if $A-(\gamma-\lambda)$ is invertible (they are the same operator). So $\gamma\in\sigma(A+\lambda)$ if and only if $\gamma-\lambda\in\sigma(A)$, i.e. $\gamma\in\sigma(A)+\lambda$.

Comment: But I haven't understand why I can do it?

Comment: Please see the edit.